# CatBoost was working on Mac M1 until 5th March, 2022

Tags: conda, apple-m1, catboost

I tried out the cat boost regressor just about a week back and now when I run it, it seems to have been uninstalled! So when I try to re-install cat boost, it says

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.`

[image]

I also searched all of GitHub for similar issues and found out they hadn't released for Mac M1 yet.
This is all the same conda environment.

Additional Info

- `conda info`

```
 active environment : data-science
    active env location : /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3/envs/data-science
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/anshumantekriwal/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /Users/anshumantekriwal/.condarc
          conda version : 4.11.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.10.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=12.2.1=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /Users/anshumantekriwal/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3/envs
                          /Users/anshumantekriwal/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.10 Darwin/21.3.0 OSX/12.2.1
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

- `conda list`

```
# packages in environment at /Users/anshumantekriwal/miniforge3/envs/data-science:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
appnope                   0.1.2           py39hca03da5_1001  
argon2-cffi               21.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     21.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
babel                     2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
blas                      2.113                  openblas    conda-forge
blas-devel                3.9.0           13_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
bleach                    4.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
c-ares                    1.18.1               h1a28f6b_0  
ca-certificates           2022.2.1             hca03da5_0  
cachetools                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39hca03da5_2  
cffi                      1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.5.1            py39hc377ac9_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
defusedxml                0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dill                      0.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
executing                 0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.4.4                hc377ac9_0  
flatbuffers               2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.29.1                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               2.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
googleapis-common-protos  1.55.0                   pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.42.0           py39h95c9599_0  
h5py                      3.6.0            py39h7fe8675_0  
hdf5                      1.12.1               h5aa262f_1  
idna                      3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
ipywidgets                7.6.5                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1           py39hca03da5_1  
jinja2                    3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
json5                     0.9.6                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-resource-usage    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            1.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyter_core              4.9.1            py39hca03da5_0  
jupyterlab                3.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-github         3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.10.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-topbar         0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.19.2               h3b8d789_0  
libblas                   3.9.0           13_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           13_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  13.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
libcurl                   7.80.0               hc6d1d07_0  
libcxx                    12.0.0               hf6beb65_1  
libedit                   3.1.20210910         h1a28f6b_0  
libev                     4.33                 h1a28f6b_1  
libffi                    3.4.2                hc377ac9_2  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_1_0_h6a59814_26  
libgfortran5              11.1.0              h6a59814_26  
libiconv                  1.16                 h1a28f6b_1  
liblapack                 3.9.0           13_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0           13_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.46.0               h95c9599_0  
libopenblas               0.3.18          openmp_h5dd58f0_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1a28f6b_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                hf27765b_1  
llvm-openmp               12.0.0               haf9daa7_1  
markdown                  3.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclassic                 0.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.12                   pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbresuse                  0.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.3                  h1a28f6b_2  
nest-asyncio              1.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.22.3                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.21.2           py39h6269429_0  
oauthlib                  3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
openblas                  0.3.18          openmp_h3b88efd_0    conda-forge
opencv-python             4.5.5.64                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1m               h1a28f6b_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003  
pillow                    9.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.2.4           py39hca03da5_0  
prometheus-client         0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
promise                   2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.28                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
pure-eval                 0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyparsing                 3.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.9.7                hc70090a_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pytz                      2021.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py39hc377ac9_2  
qtconsole                 5.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.1.2                h1a28f6b_1  
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.8                      pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                58.0.4           py39hca03da5_1  
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.37.2               h1058600_0  
stack-data                0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-datasets       4.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-deps           2.8.0                         0    apple
tensorflow-macos          2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tf-estimator-nightly      2.8.0.dev2021122109          pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.11               hb8d0fd4_0  
torch                     1.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
torch-summary             1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.1              py39h1a28f6b_0  
tqdm                      4.63.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
typing-extensions         4.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2021e                hda174b7_0  
urllib3                   1.26.8                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websocket-client          1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wrapt                     1.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.5                h1a28f6b_0  
zeromq                    4.3.4                hc377ac9_0  
zipp                      3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11               h5a0b063_4
```

Comment: Not enough details. How was it installed? There are no Conda builds for **osx-arm64**. Are you sure this is a native Conda install (add `conda info` or `conda list catboost`)?

Comment: Thanks for adding the info! We also need to know how you installed it/are trying to install it. Please add the commands that lead to error messages, not just the errors.

Comment: Also, doesn't seem there is PyPI support yet: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1526. Any possibility you originally installed in another (x86_64 - i.e., Rosetta) environment?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the environment differentiation out...
Works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Catboost early on had some issues which didn't allow it to work. It works now!